# Regex Finding the First Occurrence in a Paragraph

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a pattern like
"**Hello, I am X and My** Father's Name is Y. My Hobby's are Playing etc.".

My Target is like to Match the Pattern "**Hello, I am X and My**".

I Tried using Regex, but it is always selecting the Second "My".

i.e "Hello, I am X and My **Father's Name is Y. My**"

My Regex is `(Hello)(.*)(My?)`

I also tried `(Hello)(.*)(My?{0})`.But still its not Working.

Can you help me in this?

Comment: Thank you so much everyone. I Misunderstood the Greedy Concept. Now i am clear. Thankyou so much Tim..

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the `*` quantifier *lazy*:

```
(Hello)(.*?)(My)
```

`.*?` will match as few characters as possible (as opposed to `.*` which matches as much as it can).

Comment: But i need the First Occurrence of My. Why i have to add the lazy quantifier in the previous group Tim? Sorry I am new to regex!

Comment: @StephanThinagaran: Which part of my explanation don't you understand? If you want to match as few characters as possible between `Hello` and `My`, you need to tell that to the regex engine. That's what the `?` does in this context.

Comment: I Understand now Tim. Its like few possible characters between Hello and My. Its not indicating the number of occurrence of my. Am i right?

Comment: @StephanThinagaran: Exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex using non-greedy approach.

```
(Hello.*?My)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Hello(.*?)(?=My)(\w{2})
```

you have a greedy dinosaur but `?` will make it a lazy dinosaur

this is a bad dino who eats everything coming in its way
 .* and .+ is like that only
it will eat everything its greedy

The bad greedy dino will eat everything and then try to match It will try searching for `My` but he wont be able to find it because he has already eaten them. So, slowly he will start vomiting the letters ....slowly .. one by one unless he finds the `y` and then the `M`. so it matches the last My in your string.

When we make it lazy, He wont eat the full string and will be content on finding the first `My`. he will eat it and go to sleep :)